# If I copy a project from repository and disconnect it will the old version also disconnect?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I checked out a project from repository copied it, and have been changing the copy so I don't mess anything up ! If I disconnect the copy i have been changing will it disconnect the old copy ? I am new to SVN and I do not want to loose my changes or mess up the old one !

P.s. I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you made an independent copy of your original project, disconnecting the new copy of the project won't affect your original copy. If you don't want to lose the changes of the original copy you have to commit it and the state will be saved. In the case you commit a new version and mess up the project you can download an old version or rollback your changes